# Return data once each promise inside a promise array is fulfilled - Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am uploading files to Azure and my current implementation is to get the response back to my parent function.

This is my code:

```
export const uploadMultipleFilesToAzure = (
  uploadData: UploadMultipleToAzure[],
  handleProgress: (
    loadedBytes: number,
    fileData: UploadMultipleToAzure['fileData']
  ) => void
) => {
  const PIPELINE = newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential(), {
    retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
    keepAliveOptions: {
      // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
      enable: false,
    },
  });

  let blockBlobClient: BlockBlobClient;
  const promises: Promise<BlobUploadCommonResponse>[] = [];
  forEach(uploadData, (uploadItem) => {
    blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(uploadItem.BlobURL, PIPELINE);
    promises.push(
      blockBlobClient.uploadData(uploadItem.fileData as Blob, {
        blockSize:
          (uploadItem.fileData as Blob).size > 1024 * 1024 * 32
            ? 1024 * 1024 * 4
            : 1024 * 512,
        maxSingleShotSize: 1024 * 512,
        concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency,
        onProgress: (ev: TransferProgressEvent) =>
          handleProgress(
            ev.loadedBytes / (uploadItem.fileData as Blob).size,
            uploadItem.fileData
          ),
      })
    );
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

This is my parent function which is inside an async function:

```
const data = await uploadMultipleFilesToAzure(result, handleProgress);
```

The value of data becomes available only when all the promises are resolved, however I need to get the data as and when one promise is fulfilled.

The goal is to a call an endpoint with the fileName everytime a promise is resolved.

Please advice.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `const allDone = Promise.all([p1.then(whatever), p2.then(whateverElse)]);` the whatever `.then` functions use the data as it comes in (concurrently!) and the allDone promise is just that: it settles when everything is done. Best of both worlds.

Comment: But I do not know what p1 is right?

Comment: Sure you do. The `p1` et al promises are the ones returned by `blockBlobClient.uploadData`. Also don't forget that Promises are *values*. You can use them multiple times, in multiple places. `const arrOfPromises = [p1, p2, p3]; arrOfPromises.forEach(p => p.then(doSomethingAsDataComesIn)); const allPromisesSettled = Promise.all(arrOfPromises); const firstToFinish = Promise.race(arrOfPromises);` and none of those interfere with each other.

Comment: Can you show me in an example please?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder Could you help me out on this please?

Comment: "*call an endpoint with the fileName everytime a promise is resolved.*" - either put that endpoint call right inside the `forEach` loop, as `promises.push(blockBlobClient.uploadData(…).then(() => callEndpoint(fileName)))`, or take a callback to `uploadMultipleFilesToAzure` that does this (in exactly the same way you already use `handleProgress`). The alternative would be to implement and return an asynchronous iterator instead of returning a promise for an array.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi . Can you show me an example using asynchronous iterator?

Comment: @a2441918 No, a simple one (just `yield`ing in a loop) would mean that the uploads become sequential. Running them in parallel [is complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50586391/1048572), and actually you'd want an observable not an async iterator.

Comment: That sounds complicated. I’ll go with option 1 which returns me individual promise resolve as well as promise.all(). Thanks @Bergi.

Comment: @Bergi If you have some time, can you please modify my code and get me a solution using Observables? My end goal is to let my ApI know when each file upload is completed as well as when the whole bunch upload is completed. Thanks

Comment: Returning an observable (which requires an external library) is pretty much the same as taking a callback.

Comment: If that’s the case, I’ll go with the callback option. Thanks

Comment: @Bergi The individual callback worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With promise race, you get first promise resolved or rejected:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

But if you need all promises, i think is just a loop:

```
  });
  return promises.map(pro => pro.then(callback1));
};
```

You can bind external context declaring a function that receives promise data, and next call your callback with extra FILE_DATA! Look:

```
});
  return promises.map(pro => pro.then((dataPromise) => callback1(dataPromise, FILE_DATA)));
};
```

**After see the user gist.**

I think you not handle `pro` promise!
change this:

```
  return promises.map((pro) => {
    const file = (uploadData.find(
      (uploadItem) => pro[(uploadItem.fileData as FileWithPath).name]
    ) as UploadMultipleToAzure).fileData;
    return pro[(file as FileWithPath).name].then((dataPromise) =>
      callback(dataPromise, file)
    );
  });
```

to this:

```
  return promises.map((promise) => promise.then((pro) => {
    const file = (uploadData.find(
      (uploadItem) => pro[(uploadItem.fileData as FileWithPath).name]
    ) as UploadMultipleToAzure).fileData;
    return pro[(file as FileWithPath).name].then((dataPromise) =>
      callback(dataPromise, file)
    );
  }));
```

Comment: I tried that,  promises.map(pro => pro.then((a) => {callback1(a))); but how do I get the fileData sent back in the callback since the return is out of the for loop?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/a2441918/fa068b1a4fc96c6b6b08971e29e6e60f    I dont get the response. Please advice.