# What happens to rejected promises inside Promise.race?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Normally, when a Promise in JavaScript rejects without handling, we get `unhandled promise rejection` error.

But then what happens to all rejected promises ignored by `Promise.race` logic? Why don't they throw the same error?

Consider the following test:

```js
const normal = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(123), 100);
});

const err = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject('ops'), 500);
});

const test = Promise.race([normal, err]);

test.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The test above simply outputs `123`, but no `unhandled promise rejection` error for our `err` promise.

I'm trying to understand what happens to all those rejected promises then, hence the question.

We potentially end up with a bunch of loose promises that continue running in the background, without any error handling, and never any reporting about unhandled promise rejections. This seems kind of dangerous.

---

Case in point. I was trying to implement `combine` logic for asynchronous iterables (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585456/how-can-i-interleave-merge-async-iterables/50586391#50586391)), which requires use of `Promise.race`, while at the same time tracking rejections of any parameters passed into it, because the `combine` function needs then to reject on the next request.

Comment: When you use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) you tell the system that you only care about the first promise that is either rejected or resolved, the second one is ignored. See the documentation for details.

Comment: "*I'm trying to understand what happens to all those rejected promises then, hence the question.*" nothing happens. With `race` you only care about the first completed promise, not the rest. So, it doesn't matter that it's rejected. Same how it doesn't matter that it is fulfilled.

Comment: @fredrik Promises that are ignored by `Promise.race` continue to execute, and may result in rejection. I do not see the documentation ever saying anything like `other rejected promises are just swallowed`. You effectively end up with a bunch of loose promises that continue running in the background, and without any error handling. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @vitaly-t A promise isn't "running". The tasks that would resolve the promise are still running, yes, but you can't do anything about that since there's no cancellation mechanism.

Comment: I believe you could improve your question by showing an example that does fire the unhandled event and the same with just the Promise.race going there. No time to dig the specs here, but the logical explanation is that `Promise.race()` does internally and conceptually call both `then` and `catch`, meaning the promise is actually handled by it, even if the handler of the throwing Promise would just do nothing here (think of it as `.catch((reason) => { if(firstFired) { return; }...`.

Comment: Why not use Promise.all, isnt it like combine?

Comment: @Yftach You're thinking of the wrong `combine` logic. I was talking about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585456/how-can-i-interleave-merge-async-iterables).

Comment: @Kaiido `catch` is never called internally. It's always `.then()` with two arguments.

Comment: @Bergi If you attach `catch` to that `err` promise, it gets caught.

Comment: @vitaly-t there why would you use Promise.race for this case then? By definition the promises that "lost the race" are discarded

Comment: @Yftach It is explained at the bottom of my question (case in point).

Comment: @Bergi "and conceptually"

Comment: @Kaiido It seems like you have a different conceptualisation. To me (and to the spec), `then` is where the actual stuff happens, `catch` is just a convenience wrapper.

Comment: @Bergi I only meant it to convey that the `onRejected` callback was also passed. That was colloquial talk, which I guess is fine in a comment stating "No time to dig the specs here", no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Normally, when a Promise in JavaScript rejects without handling, we get
> `unhandled promise rejection` error.

Yes, this happens when a promise is getting rejected that had never gotten `.then()` called on it to install handlers, i.e. one that is the final promise of a chain.

(Notice that `.catch(onRejected)` internally delegates tot `.then(undefined, onRejected)`, so the promise is getting marked as handled the same.)

> But then what happens to all rejected promises ignored by `Promise.race` logic? Why don't they throw the same error?

The `Promise.race` does call `.then()` on all promises in its argument, marking them as handled:

```
Promise.race = function(thenables) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (const thenable of thenables) {
            Promise.resolve(thenable).then(resolve, reject);
        }
    });
};
```

Notice it doesn't re-throw the error when the outer promise is already resolved, it's just getting ignored. This is by design: when using `Promise.race`, you state that you are only interested in the first result, and everything else can be discarded. Causing unhandled promise rejections from the promises that didn't win the race to crash your application would be rather disruptive.

Comment: In my example, if we attach handlers: `err.then().catch()`, we will see that `.then` is never called, but `.catch` is called. So I don't know about `Promise.race` calling `then`, it doesn't look that way.

Comment: @vitaly-t Which example? No, don't attach handlers using `p.then(onFulfilled).catch(onRejected)`, [use `p.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). The implementation of `Promise.race` I gave is a quite literal translation of the spec text.

Comment: The example I provided in my question, which has promise `err` that errors. I attached `then` and `catch` to it, and only `catch` is called, which is what I expected. My question arose from the fact that even though it does reject, nothing happens if I do not add `catch` to it at all.

Comment: @vitaly-t The code snippet in the question has neither `err.then(…)` nor `err.catch(…)`, only `Promise.race([…, err])`, which does `err.then(…, …)` internally. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like having `.then(cb)` is enough to prevent the unhandledrejection event to fire, it's not, you need to pass the catcher too.

Comment: @Kaiido It absolutely is. When doing `const p2 = p1.then(cb)`, no unhandledrejection will fire on `p1`. Of course, when `p1` rejects `p2` will also get rejected, and an unhandledrejection will fire on *that* - unless you install some further handlers via `p2.then(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

> The Promise.race() method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise.

Your code fulfills because the faster promise calls `resolve`. Swap them around and it rejects.

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(reject, 100, 'two');
});

Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
}).catch((value) => {
  console.log('error ', value);
});
```

Comment: This isn't what I asked about. I asked about what happens to rejected promises ignored by `Promise.race`.

Comment: @vitaly-t — Well. Nothing.

Comment: Keyword there is: Ignored. They resolve or reject as per normal. Anything listening for that will trigger. Promise.race won't because it ignores them.

Comment: I guess me asking this here can be summarized as `here goes nothing`.