# How to Efficiently Print Chronologically Ordered Entries from Multiple DataStreams with Asynchronous nextAsync Calls?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

**Setup:**
I have a `DataStream` class that provides a `nextAsync` function to retrieve the next entry. Each entry consists of a message and a timestamp. Entries within a single DataStream are chronologically ordered, but the number of entries is unknown. The `nextAsync` function continues to return entries until it finally returns false, indicating that the data source is exhausted.

**Problem Description:**
I have `n` DataStreams, and my goal is to print entries ordered chronologically across all of them. The catch is that the `nextAsync` function returns a promise with a slight (millisecond-level) delay. Importantly, entries across different DataStreams have no inherent chronological order concerning each other. Additionally, the DataStreams can be quite extensive, making it inefficient to store all their entries simultaneously.

**Proposed Solution:**
My idea is to utilize a `min-priority queue` that stores objects containing entries and their corresponding DataStream index, ordered by timestamps. The object structure would look like this:

```
{
   message,
   timestamp,
   indexOfDataStream,
}
```

My approach involves using a while loop that continues until the priority queue is empty. In each iteration, I retrieve and print the entry with the minimum timestamp and employ the indexOfDataStream to fetch the next entry for that DataStream using `await nextAsync`, subsequently pushing it back into the priority queue.

While my proposed solution synchronizes all the calls, I'm interested in optimizing the code for faster execution. Are there any techniques or approaches to improve the runtime efficiency of this process?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I Interleave / merge async iterables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50585456/1048572) which should exactly solve your problem

Comment: I think your approach is flawed. Wouldn't "*using a while loop that continues until the priority queue is empty*" return immediately, since the queue is empty while asynchronously fetching the first entries? And it might get empty at any time - I would in fact expect it to be empty most of the time.