# Await for one promise that returns a truthy value in an array of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise array with a 100 promises. I want to await until a single promise fulfills with a truthy value. Also, I want to make sure only x promises run concurrently (set the limit).

I've looked into methods like `bluebird.any` and `bluebird.some` but they don't do have a concurrency option.

How do I do this?

Comment: promises don't run. A promise is just the future result of some code executed.

Comment: Check this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit

Comment: For waiting for a single promise is it a single particular promise or any of the concurrent promises? if it is any promise.race is something you can look into along with p-limit library above.

Comment: Check there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639432/what-is-the-best-way-to-limit-concurrency-when-using-es6s-promise-all

Comment: Check out [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), which has operator [waitRace](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/waitRace.html), so you can remap a sequence into promises, and then control how many promises run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Bluebird promise.map should solve your issue along with the option of concurrency.

```
promise.map(promiseArray, {concurrency: 4})
```

The concurrency here basically limits the number of promises running state. If you make concurrency to 1, then they execute serially.

Comment: This does indeed solve the concurrency and I was aware of it. But it waits for all the promises to resolve. I just need to wait until one of them resolves with a truthy value.