# Limit number of tasks processed simultaneously in loop

Tags: node.js, typescript

I define a function named `fn` which I then run in the background as part of a bigger service.

The function `fn` retrieves messages from a message queue one by one, and processes each message. Processing of each message can take between 1 and 10 minutes (`longProcess()`).

Using the following code, the `for await` loop waits for new messages and processes each one, and then fetches a new message once the processing is complete.

```js
const fn = async (subscription: AsyncIterable) => {
    subscription.pullOne();
    for await (const msg of subscription) {
        await longProcess(msg);
        subscription.pullOne();
    }
    subscription.close();
};

fn(subscription).then(() => {});
```

If I remove the `await` from before `longProcess(msg)`, messages are sent to be processed as soon as they are received, which is what I want, but I only want a maximum of 5 messages to be processed simultaneously.

I don't want any more messages to be pulled before the current messages are done processing (so that other subscribers may pull and process them).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639432/what-is-the-best-way-to-limit-concurrency-when-using-es6s-promise-all) deals with a very similar case, but I can't seem to find a solution that actually works and provides an elegant solution.

I tried using the [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck) library by defining a concurrency limit, but I can't figure out how to stop the loop from fetching more messages before the active processing is finished.

```js
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
    maxConcurrent: 5,
});

const fn = async (subscription: AsyncIterable) => {
    subscription.pullOne();
    for await (const msg of subscription) {
        limiter.schedule(() => longProcess(msg));
        subscription.pullOne();
    }
    subscription.close();
};
```

Comment: Maybe it worths splitting `subscription` into several arrays per 5 elements and then smth like `Promise.all` ?

Comment: Messages are constantly sent to subscription, I'm not sure if splitting every 5 into a separate array will be efficient. Also, theoretically, I may only receive 1 or 2 messages at a given time, and then I wouldn't even have 5 messages to put aside. 
I'm more interested in how to limit the `for await` so that more messages aren't pulled until the `limiter` is free to process more messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can try processing them in batches/chunks of <= 5 items at a time

```js
// helper function
async function take(aIterable, count) {
  const res = [];
  let done = false
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const next = await aIterable.next()
    if(!next.done) res.push(next.value)
    done = next.done;
  }
  return [res, done];
}

const fn = async (subscription) => {
    subscription.pullOne();
    let done = false;
    while (!done) {
        let [batch, _done] = await take(subscription, 5);
        done = _done;
        await Promise.allSettled(batch.map(msg => longProcess(msg)));
        // subscription.pullOne();
    }
    subscription.close();
};
```

Comment: Will this work if `subscription` is an `AsyncIterable`?

Comment: It wouldn't work but can be made to work with some changes. is subscription AsyncIterable?

Comment: @Charles pullOne and close doesn't exit on AsyncIterable. But I have edited this to work with normal AsyncIterable. If you are using a custom library for it, then decide where to call pullOne, I think close is in the right place, no?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Where is `msg` in all of this? I still need to call `longProcess` with `msg` as a parameter, a possibly other parameters going forward. Also, my IDE shows an error for `map`: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<PromiseSettledResult<any>[]>'.`

Comment: Sorry, the `map` is on`batch`. I have also explicitly specified the msg. (Updated the answer) Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I made some small modifications to fit this to my code (e.g. `take` returns an object because an array makes less sense to me), but it seems to get stuck inside `take` in the `for`'s second iteration. So likely getting stuck on `const next = await aIterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]().next()`. If I undersstand correctly this requires at least 5 messages to come through before processing even begins. I think I may give up on this altogether because it's becoming a real pain getting this to work. This would have been much more straightforward to implement using goroutines and channels in Go.